# Using Django for existing html pages, and using my own login form

Tags: php, django, authentication

I have a pretty simple website, which consists of some online courses. All I need on the backend is a login system, and to use it to restrict access to courses. I've already done the frontend work, the html pages are all done. I want to try using Django, but when I was looking at tutorials to set up a login system, they all used the default login view, which is very plain.. I have a modal login form on my website (the login appears on index.html itself, not a separate login.html page).

How can I use the looks of my login form with Django, to create a secure login? Would using Django be too much of a hassle, should I just use PHP instead? I'm new to both PHP and Django (although I know Python).

Comment: What do you mean by "use the looks of login form with Django to create a secure login?"

Comment: As in, using the css and html that I've already written for my login box, as opposed to using django's login view, which is very plain. However, I obviously still want the customised login form to be as secure as the default django template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a customized Django login template (in your case it already exists in the `index.html`). As many users have this kind of task to solve there is a standard functionality for that.

1. You configure your URL routes for login and logout systems (Not only in the url config but in the `settings.py` too for redirects etc.). For an specific example take a look at the link in the end.
2. You integrate and adjust your `index.html` as a custom login template. Take a look at the [Django manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/) on forms)

And then you're good to go, if you set up the whole user infrastructure in Django already. If you need a specific example take a look at [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/06/27/how-to-use-djangos-built-in-login-system.html).

### Personal opinion

Don't use PHP, just go all the way with Django. It is probably not easy for you to migrate your whole page in the beginning, but it will be worth shortly after. Django is not only way faster and more secure than PHP, but also highly maintainable after setup.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, that's why I'm hesitant about PHP- it'll be easier to integrate but in the end Django's less messy. Also, what should I do if I want to ask for the user's name during registration too?

Comment: As there is no default registration form provided, you can use your own registration/ signup form. Just create a form within Django and add your value. Here is an [example implementation](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html) for that.

Comment: And what would I have to do to make the forms secure? Do I have to do anything else apart from using `{% csrf_token %}`? What about sql injection?

Comment: SQL injections are mainly prevented by Django as it interprets the python statements individually to each connected database. Take a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/security/#sql-injection-protection) for further informations. For further questions please add a seperate question. :)

Comment: The advice about Django being "more secure than PHP" is completely incorrect. You can't compare a framework (Django) to a language (PHP) - the comparison would be with something like Symfony, a PHP framework. And there is not anything intrinsically less secure with PHP or its frameworks - to a limited degree it matters how much security analysis is done on the framework. However, the biggest contributor to security problems is the application implementer, regardless of whether they are using a framework - they can shoot themselves in the foot in any language.